# How do you replace content generated by custom fields with custom blocks in Block Editor?

Tags: theme-development, custom-field, block-editor

I am wanting to support the new Block Editor for a theme that I made for a client. However, one of the page types has part of the theme that is displayed depending on whether custom fields are set that the client can modify below the editor (using Toolset Types plugin). It essentially will split the content into two inline sections show the embeds for videos and links to files one side while the rest of the content of the post to the right.

Is there a way to add custom blocks that will essentially split the content if set and allow the user to change the value (url of embed/file) so that it looks like what will end up on the site?

If that is not a solution, is there a way to add placeholders, if custom fields are being used with values? I don't want to actually add to the content itself since that would affect what is currently being displayed in the theme as it is now. If I create new blocks I would refactor the theme's pages to account for the change.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: There are several things here, for the first one (settings that affect the block) would you be ok including these settings as attributes of the block rather than custom fields?

Comment: If it was actually a better and easier way for the content writers to manage it, then yes I wouldn't mind replacing the fields with blocks. I just don't know how I would go about doing it, since I am finding little usable information. WordPress doesn't really do a "What's different?" like PHP does, so finding good details is hard since their manual has barely enough information to get someone started.